# Not getting attachments from Nearby Messages API

Tags: google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I am using Nearby messages API for android. I was getting the attachments using API before, till end of January. However, it has abruptly stopped working. I can see the request calls my app making in the google cloud console. However, I am not getting any attachment. Is there anything that has been changed on the API end?

Answer (score 0):

I work on the Nearby team. We've recently discovered and fixed a problem with the default message filter, which might be what's affecting you (e.g. if you don't provide a message filter at all). The fix is rolling out within the next day or two. Apologies!