# google nearby not getting attachments

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

We are currently implementing **Google Nearby** for our beacon network. We have implemented the Google Nearby API for Android. We have successfully subscribed and see that API calls are being made. However we do not see any attachments.

Our setup:

1. We have created a project 'project A' where we have registered the beacons
2. We have created a project called 'project B'
3. We have created beacon attachments under project A with the name space of 'project B'

Two questions:

1. We are using the API key of project B to retrieve the attachments. However after we have successfully subscribed we do not see any attachments. We have tried both foreground and background subscription. Any suggestions?
2. If we are changing the API key with other characters we still get an OK message for the subscription. Wondering how we can test GoogleApiClient?

Comment: Can this be the problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825543/not-getting-attachments-from-nearby-messages-api

Comment: Maybe. We are currently implementing filters to rule out that possibility.

Comment: @Dietatko I can't place a comment on that questions to ask for an update since i am a newbie